# Deal with Intent Action (ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS) not being found

Tags: android, networking, settings

I am trying to use  `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS` from [This API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS)
but it is giving an error.

I think its matching Activity may not exist.

How can I use it. I want to make an application which can directly give me list of available network operators.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget29); 
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget28); 
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            //@Override public void onClick(View v) {
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell us how you're using it (code snippet), and what error you're getting?

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget29);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget28);
        
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          //@Override
         
          public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: @Meet where's the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply attempt to send them to the list of operators and deal with the situation of it not being possible:

```
 try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("YourApp", "Activity not found, android settings not launched");
    }
```

or

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
    boolean available = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null;
    if(available){
        Log.e("YourApp", "Activity found");
        // act appropriately .. show a button, to then allow the behaviour
    }
```